# activating e-mail with activate.php

Tags: php

I am trying to write a registration script and user should activate his e-mail.
so I have `activate.php` for that.

Logic is changing `md5 hash` to `1` in `activated` colomn. So after user can sign-in.

But even if I try to activate with correct `md5 hash` my page says `Wrong activation code.`

I can't see anything wrong, there is no database problem. I checked like ten times.

Is there anybody can give me a hand?

**activate.php**

```
<?php require_once('config.php');
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {  
     echo $e->getMessage(); 
     die(); 
}

 //The Activation key will always be 32 since it is MD5 Hash
if (isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32))
 { $key = $_GET['key']; }

   $search = $handler->query("SELECT activated FROM members WHERE activated='$key'");
   $match  = $search->fetchColumn();

    if($match > 0){ 

 // Update the database to set the "activation" field to 1

 $result = $handler->query("UPDATE members SET activated = 1 WHERE activated='$key' LIMIT 1");

        if($result){
            echo "Activated";       
        }

        else{
            echo "database problem.";
        }

}
        elseif($match == 0){ 
            echo "Wrong activation code.";
        }

?>
```

When I visit `activate.php??key=d85516205a57dcf1cfd228c19e3f3eff` it doesn't `Activated` but, it's `Wrong activation code.`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). If the URL is `activate.php?key=x'%20or%201=%20--` (i.e., `key` is `x' or 1=1 --`) you're toast; that would activate every single user. That's just one example. You need to use prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks Ed, i tried but it didn't work as you thought. This is the result I get. `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation`

Comment: Actually, I have a bit of a typo; an attacker would need to add a space to the end of the key (`activate.php?key=x'%20or%201=1%20--%20`). The example in my original comment will result in queries containing `--'` and `--LIMIT 1`, which will throw syntax errors. With the space ( `-- '` and `-- LIMIT 1`) they will not. The point is that this code is exploitable in a pretty obvious way; if you put it out in the wild, it *will* be exploited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security first.

Use PDO prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

And try this code, let's see if it's going to work.

```
<?php require_once('config.php');
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {  
     echo $e->getMessage(); 
     die(); 
}

//collect value from the url
$key = trim($_GET['key']);

//if key is set, not empty and 32 characters.
if(isset($key) && !empty($key) && (strlen($key) == 32)){

    //update users record set the activated column to "1" where the key value match the one provided in url
    $stmt = $handler->prepare("UPDATE members SET activated = '1' WHERE activated = :key LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':key' => $key
    ));

    //if the row was updated redirect the user
    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){

        //good news
         echo "Your account is activated."; 
        exit;

    } else {
        echo "Your account could not be activated."; 
    }

} else {
    echo "We need right code to confirm your membership.";
} 
?>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you very much. It looks also safe against Ed :)